# php best way to replace backticks with single quote?

Tags: php, sql

I have been using this for a while without any problems...

```
$string = str_replace(array("`",chr(96)),array("'","'"), $string);
```

However, I just noticed that it doesn't always work for some reason... Am I missing another variation? Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: Provide an example showing when it doesn't work.

Comment: My mistake, the user just contacted me again and we noticed it was because he was using an acute accent and not the backtick. I have updated the code to also replace chr(180) and this has been resolved. Question can be deleted.

Comment: It may be of help in the future to somebody. Rather not delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the PHP documentation for [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

You need to pass the subject of the replace in order for it to work.

```
$string = str_replace(array("`",chr(96)),array("'","'"), $string);
```

Comment: The subject is there...

Comment: It was not when he posted it, and he deleted the comment saying so on this answer. How nice.

Comment: Ha, good to know.  Yes, I see his edit now.

Answer (score 3):

Your string probably contains unicode fancy quotes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs), and you are misinterpreting them as backticks.  This can help with that: http://alanwhipple.com/2011/06/04/php-clean-encoding-issues-smart-curly-quotes-em-dashes/

Code copied in case the original site changes or goes away:

```
<?php
/**
 * cleanEncoding deals with pesky characters like curly smart quotes and em dashes (and some other encoding related problems)
 *
 * @param string $text Text string to cleanup / convert
 * @param string $type 'standard' for standard characters, 'reference' for decimal numerical character reference
 *
 * @return $text Cleaned up UTF-8 string
 */
function cleanEncoding( $text, $type='standard' ){
    // determine the encoding before we touch it
    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1');
    // The characters to output
    if ( $type=='standard' ){
        $outp_chr = array('...',          "'",            "'",            '"',            '"',            '•',            '-',            '-'); // run of the mill standard characters
    } elseif ( $type=='reference' ) {
        $outp_chr = array('&#8230;',      '&#8216;',      '&#8217;',      '&#8220;',      '&#8221;',      '&#8226;',      '&#8211;',      '&#8212;'); // decimal numerical character references
    }
    // The characters to replace (purposely indented for comparison)
        $utf8_chr = array("\xe2\x80\xa6", "\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", '\xe2\x80\xa2', "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94"); // UTF-8 hex characters
        $winc_chr = array(chr(133),       chr(145),       chr(146),       chr(147),       chr(148),       chr(149),       chr(150),       chr(151)); // ASCII characters (found in Windows-1252)
    // First, replace UTF-8 characters.
    $text = str_replace( $utf8_chr, $outp_chr, $text);
    // Next, replace Windows-1252 characters.
    $text = str_replace( $winc_chr, $outp_chr, $text);
    // even if the string seems to be UTF-8, we can't trust it, so convert it to UTF-8 anyway
    $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', $encoding);
    return $text;
}

?>
```